# Create new Child on Parent's show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

On the show view of an existing Parent, I would like to have a form to create Children.

I've figured out how to create a Child form and include it on the Parent's show, but not how to exclude the parent_id field. How can I assign a parent_id to a child without using a form field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best way to handle this is by using member routes for the parent controller so that when you create the child, you always know which parent it belongs to through the routing. For example:

```
# routes.rb
resources :parents do
  member do
    post 'create_child'
  end
end
```

And then in your view

```
# parents/show.html.erb
<%= form_for @child, :url => create_child_parent_path(@parent) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

And finally in your controller

```
# parents_controller.rb
def create_child
  @parent = Parent.find(params[:id])
  @child = @parent.children.build(params[:child])
  if @child.save
    @child = Child.new
  end
  render :action => :show
end
```

The key here is that even though the form contains no information about the parent, the parent_id gets assigned by default when you use the build method on the association.